# Typecasting for ViewControllers in swift

Tags: swift, typecasting-operator

I’m quite new to iOS development and swift.

I’m seeing something like this quite often

```
let vc = window?.rootViewController as! MainViewController
```

Would someone mind explaining type casting and what the purpose of this is to me? I’ve been trying to find other questions or just a basic explanation of the purpose - but I’m not having much luck.

Thanks

Comment: That line should not be written like that. `window` could be `nil` - crash. The root controller might not be of type `MainViewController` - crash.

Comment: Start by reading the [Type Casting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html) chapter in the Swift book (and the rest of the book too).

Comment: in the book that I'm going through this was part of the code that I was given to write to be able to pull data across different ViewControllers 

`let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let itemsController = navController.topViewController as! ItemsViewController
        itemsController.itemStore = itemStore`

I've also seen

`let tabbar = tabBarViewController as! CustomTabBarController`

when trying to connect to a variable that was set in CustomTabBarController


so is this code just bad? How else would I do that?

Comment: also - I read that, and I understand the idea of down casting - but I've seen as? and as! used in other contexts and I'm just not clear on the purpose.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. You state that you understand down casting then you state that are not clear on `as` which is how you cast. So please clarify. What is it exactly that you are unclear with?

Comment: Ok, I suppose I do not understand the above execution. In the book it talks about downcasting to two different types of classes either musicItem of movieItem through a for loop. In my above examples it's outside of a for loop, and it's setting it to a variable to do further work with. So, if you asked me to use type casting to do a for loop I could handle that... but when it comes to what the purpose is using casting to initialize a variable and then do something else with it I'm not so sure. I hope that clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is a crash in the making. The `as` construct casts a variable of a general type to a more specific type. If it can fail, you need to add a `?` (`as?`) or an exclamation point (`as!`) The form with an exclamation point is known as a "force cast". It tries to cast the object to a different type, **and will crash if the cast fails. Thus it is a bad idea and should be avoided.**

Better to use code like this:

```
func someFunc() {
    guard let vc = window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController else {
       return
    }
    //Code that depends on vc being cast to type MainViewController
}
```

(Read up on the `guard` statement in the Apple Swift iBook for more information.)

Even this code is better than what you posted:

```
func someFunc() {
    guard let vc = window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController else {
       fatalError("Unable to cast rootViewController to type MainViewController")
    }
    //Code that depends on vc being cast to type MainViewController
}
```

The second version will still crash, but will display a very clear message in the console when it **does** crash, so you can tell what went wrong.

Comment: this would explain why I can't find any resources on what this means. What is best practice then in passing data back and forth in between various viewcontrollers then?

Comment: There are ≈200,000 threads on how to pass data between view controllers. Google is your friend...

Comment: thanks - I looked at an example and in that example it had the same type of casting:

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
      //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
      // segues attached to same view
      var detailVC = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController;
      detailVC.toPass = textField.text
    }
}`


how does this differ from mine above? With of course the if statement. is casting safe as long as you wrap it appropriately?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's nearly impossible to read. The code you posted shouldn't compile.